# ValueError for adfuller test python

Tags: programming

[Solved] For the below code, I get a **ValueError:could not convert string to float**. I have tried to search from the forum but still not able to find the solution.

Hope for help. Thanks in advance.

[Solution] There is error for my data in csv file, e.g. there is some unknown format data like "?0.2" instead of "0.2" inside the csv datafield.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

%matplotlib inline

df=pd.read_csv("./min-temp.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df=df.iloc[:,0].values
dftest = adfuller(df, autolag="AIC")
```

The df result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/917nO.jpg)

Value Error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqB4Z.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j51wK.jpg)

Comment: Did you check the datatype of the elements in your df? Are there any NA’s?

Comment: Print the df (at least some rows) and look at the values. Some may be wrong.

Comment: Solved, thanks. There is indeed some errors for csv data output.